# How to make full background color in skeleton, responsive 960 grid?

Tags: skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to achieve full background width, using skeleton framework. For now, bad luck.

Here's how it looks now : http://shrani.si/f/3A/Uy/28somHnh/capture.png

Thanks everyone for helping me.

```
<div class="container"> 
<div id="portfolio-color">

<div class="sixteen columns">
<div id="color">
<div class="five columns offset-by-four">LATEST WORK



</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Sure, let me just pull up my telepathic abilities... done. Now I've got to find where you store your code. Oh, there it is! Ah, see all you have to do is change _____ to _____. But in all seriousness, where's your code...?

Comment: Anyone? I need to find solution, huh...

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by putting `.container` onto a full width wrapping element. Something like this:

See dabblet here http://dabblet.com/gist/6476534

```
<style>
    @import url(import.skeleton.before.css)
    .wrapper {width: 100%;}
    .color-one {background-color: red;}
    .color-two {background-color: green;}
</stlye>

<div class="wrapper color-one">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sixteen columns"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper color-two">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="five columns offset-by-four"></div>
        <div class="eleven columns"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```